# easygui_qt running only once when starting Spyder

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with Python 3.8.

I am trying to make a gui appear where the user has to write a float and this value is passed on to some function for some calculations.

I am using easygui_qt and it works as intended if I open Spyder and run the program. But if I run it the second time, it does not show the popoup any more and it does not work. The only time it works is if I close the Spyder and open it again.

> import easygui_qt as easy

> valueReceived = easy.get_float("Write the desired value", "Desired value", 10, -20, 20, 3)

Is there anything I should be doing to make it popup again when I press play?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution but so far all I've found. If you run the demo before every call then hit 'cancel' I have been successfully able to run subsequent easygui calls.

```
import easygui as gui

gui.egdemo()  #will need to hit cancel in lower left corner

openfile = gui.fileopenbox(title="Open File")

gui.egdemo()  #will need to hit cancel in lower left corner

savefile = gui.filesavebox(title="Save as", default='.csv')
```